# How to make sure a filtered update view is safe?

Tags: django, django-views

I've made a list view of users that are part of a group named `Manager`.
I've made a link to edit those users.

The link looks like: `http://localhost:8000/en/manager/edit/12`

So this is about "editing the User number 12".

If you manually change `12` to `1`, it works... so what is the way to properly make sure the User you're editing belongs to the group `Manager`?

I've tried to override `get_object` and return `None` if the User doesn't belong to the `Manager` group but it doesn't make sense:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    group = Group.objects.get(name="Manager")
    try:
        return User.objects\
                   .filter(groups__in=[group])\
                   .get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've overriden the `get()` method like this:

```
class ManagerUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = RegisterManagerForm
    template_name = 'crud/manager/update.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = Group.objects.get(name="Manager")
        try:
            User.objects.filter(groups__in=[group])\
                        .get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('manager_list'))
        return super(ManagerUpdateView, self).get(request,
                                                  *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Or raise PermissionDenied

Comment: Nice suggestion I'll do it when I have more than 3femtoseconds for myself!